# C functions visibility

Tags: c

How do I make a C function visible for functions only in other certains .c files?

Let's suppose I have a foo1 function wich calls other foo2 function (in differents .c files) and I want to call foo1 from my main function, but I want foo2 to be invisible for any function other than foo1, like this:

```
/**
    foo1.c
*/
void foo1()
{
    if (condition_is_true){
        foo2();
    }
}

/**
    foo2.c
*/
#include <stdio.h>

void foo2()
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
}

/**
    main.c
*/
void foo1(void);
void foo2(void);

int main()
{
    foo1();
    foo2(); /*unresolved external*/
}
```

And when compiling

```
$ cc -omain main.c foo1.c foo2.c
```

I want the linker to complain "undefined reference to `foo2'".

Comment: The only thing you can do is not `include` the header for `foo2` in `main.c`.

Comment: C and C++ are not the same language, despite their similarities. Please use only the tags that are actually relevant to your question, and don't add them just because they seem similar or contain words or phrases that are familiar. Tags have meaning here, both in getting questions to the attention of those who can answer it and for classifying them for future users here who are searching for a solution to their problem. Thanks.

Comment: In that case, you can define `foo2()` as static function, inside the same .c file of `foo1()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, if you want to make a function in one .c source code file visible in another .c source file, you place the definition of that function into a .h file and include it into the .c file you want it visible in.  For example:

```
file foo1.c
int somefunc1(some parameters)
  {
    Do some stuff.
  }

file foo1.h
int somefunc1(some parameters);

file foo2.c
#include "foo1.h"

int foo2(Some parameters)
  {
    Do some stuff.
    foo1(asdfasdf)
    Do some more stuff.
  }
```

That is generally what you do.  However, what you are asking for is the exact opposite.  I'm not sure why you want an undefined reference when the linker runs, but the way that you have set your compile, those files will get passed to the linker.  So the only thing that you can do is not have foo2.c on the file list.  If you are using something from one of the main libraries, it still gets linked in even if you don't specify the include file.  For instance:

```
$$$ ->more test3.c

int main(void)
  {
    printf("hello world\n");
    return(0);
  }


$$$ ->clang -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -o test3 test3.c
test3.c:8:5: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'printf' with type 'int (const char *, ...)'
    printf("hello world\n");
    ^
test3.c:8:5: note: please include the header <stdio.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'printf'
1 warning generated.
```

So what you are asking for I don't really think can or should be done.